# Manipulation of pdf by java?

Tags: java, pdf

I have to create a project in which I manipulate a pdf file using java.  I attached the required jar file. Can anyone provide a simple manipulation program?

Comment: are we talking manipulating an existing pdf, or creating one?

Comment: Attached required jar file? I don't think you can.

Comment: No, Stack Overflow is not for "providing" programs. If you try to write it on your own and run into a specific problem, you can ask about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at IText -http://itextpdf.com/. It has lots of features for creating as we'll as manipulating PDFs. It has many examples you can refer to.

Comment: Accept an answer and up vote if its worth it